# get webpage print screen, php/unix

Tags: php, linux, unix

How to remotely get web page print screen? Using linux/unix or php tools.
User enters the page address and I want to save the appearance on the server (as a image).

Comment: Save as a picture ? save as a html file ?

Answer (score 2):

You want a headless web browser (i.e. one that you can run from the command line with no graphical interface). One such possibility is [PhantomJS](http://www.phantomjs.org/), which uses the webkit rendering engine.

Specifically you want the [`render()` method](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/Interface#render%28fileName%29).

From the Rendering example on the [examples page](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/QuickStart), save the following as `rasterize.js`:

```
var page = new WebPage(),
    address, output, size;

if (phantom.args.length < 2 || phantom.args.length > 3) {
    console.log('Usage: rasterize.js URL filename');
    phantom.exit();
} else {
    address = phantom.args[0];
    output = phantom.args[1];
    page.viewportSize = { width: 600, height: 600 };
    page.open(address, function (status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('Unable to load the address!');
        } else {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                page.render(output);
                phantom.exit();
            }, 200);
        }
    });
}
```

And then run it:

```
phantomjs rasterize.js http://ariya.github.com/svg/tiger.svg tiger.png
```